# Generate a 9 digit Integer in java without repeating the same number

Tags: java

I am new to java programming and I am using databases to create a simple Bank Management system. I need to create user accounts with an account number with 9 digits, that does not start with 0. also, all the account numbers must be different(one account number can have repeating digits). Every time I run the program, it should give me a 9-digit number that is not stored in the 'accounts' table under 'account_number' in the 'login_info' database.

### The program runs like this,

- User goes to the login page
- If he does not have an account he can go to the create account page
- create account page has 3 tabs, Personnel info, bank account info, and online account info
- user must fill out personnel info got be able to go to the bank account info
- when the user goes to bank account info, it shows the previously filled items (Personel info) and a couple of additional items - Bank account type and account number
- The account number must be generated when the user goes to the bank account info tab. The user cannot change the account number. (The account number must be one that has not been saved in the database before)**This is the step I am stuck**
- After selecting the account type, the user can go to the online account info page and select a unique username and password
- After that, the user can hit create account button to create his bank account along with the online account or he can exit the program if he is having second thoughts
- When the user hit create account button, a query will run and insert data into MySQL tables. This is the point where the account is created.

The program runs beautifully, but I can't seem to generate a unique bank account number. Other steps are already completed.

(This is not for any commercial products, just a project I work on to get myself acquainted with database handling with java.)

Any Idea how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use an autoincrementing number that starts from 100000000. How you do that depends on the database engine you're using.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Hibernate and use '@GeneratedValue' and '@SequenceGenerator' annotations

Comment: Since the question is Java, the auto-incrementing account number field should be created when the entity is created rather than when the entity is persisted to the database, yes?

Comment: @scottb, Yes. I need to generate the account number first, and after the user confirms the data, the query should run and the data should be added to the table.

Comment: Looks like 3,265,920 total combinations. If 9-digit number which doesn't start with 0, and does not re-use any digits, then: 9 choices for first digit (1-9), 9 choices for 2nd (0 is available, so 0-9 though something used for 1st digit), 8 choices for (3rd), etc., so `9*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2` combinations or 3,265,920.

Comment: I had an idea that you could pre-generate all valid 9-digit account IDs, and mark all as "unclaimed" or something. Then the flow becomes: query database for account ID where unclaimed=true limit 1, mark it as "pending", present to user, if they consent then mark it "claimed". No messing around with numeric things beyond the initial step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach you could take, elaborating on my comments posted above:

- pre-calculate all valid account numbers – there are a total of 3,265,920 valid combinations

  - 9 choices for first digit: 1-9,
  - 9 choices for 2nd digit: 0 is available, so 10 possible digits (0-9) except that something was used for the 1st digit
  - 8 choices for 3rd, etc.
  - so: `9*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2` combinations
- populate each of those ~3 million numbers into the database table
- include a "status" field to represent things like: "unclaimed", "pending", "claimed"
- all account numbers start out as "unclaimed"

In your Java app, when you want to present the user with a candidate account number, you can use the database to update a single row from "unclaimed" to "pending" and return that account number – so the database would enforce correctness even if multiple callers simultaneously try to set up a new account. Something like: "update accounts where status=unclaimed set status=pending limit 1" and return the updated row.

From there:

- If the user accepts the account number, simply change the status from "pending" to "claimed"
- If they decline, change it back to "unclaimed"

This approach would allow you to do numeric specifics only once, up front, when creating all initial unclaimed accounts. It does have a potential drawback that you have 3 million rows sitting there unused, but there is a nice simplicity overall – no further combinations to worry about, or generating a number and then involving the database to see if that number is claimed or not (and re-generating if number in use), or any kind of scanning through the database to use as input for the number selecting process, or whatever other ideas people might come up with. Just do the work up front.

Comment: This is the only realistic solution to date, using a database and providing for some transactionality and concurrency. However, I believe that you misinterpreted the OP's requirement that "all the account numbers must be different." I am confident this permits repeating digits in an account number, and simply means that every number as a whole should be unique.

Comment: I took _"all the account numbers must be different"_ to refer to the digits within, because otherwise it's saying that two users cannot have the same account number (which seems obvious, so why clarify that). But yes, if digits are re-usable, then this approach still works, only with larger space for account numbers. In either case, it isn't necessary to create _all possible_ account numbers up front, just _some_. Start with 10,000 account numbers and use them up before creating another block of 10,000 (or whatever block size).

Comment: @Kaan, yes, Thank you very much, this gives me an idea of how to do it. Also, we can use the same integer in one account number multiple times. Sorry about the mistake I made in posting the question.

Comment: @TKBK531 Great. You'll have way more than 3 million available account numbers that way. Letting the database do the work for you really makes this a whole lot easier. If you were super determined and didn't care about how much time it cost, or about overall system complexity, one _could_ do this in code. But the database can easily do most of the heavy lifting for you around data and concurrency correctness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number to be random, create a number from 0 to 899 999 999 and then add 100 000 000 (so the first will never be 0). If the numbers are stored in an Arraylist (in this case called nums), the following code should help:

```
        int num;
        Do{
            num = (int)(Math.random()*800000000)+100000000;
        }while (nums.contains(num));
        nums.add(num);
```

Comment: Checking whether a (billion entry) list contains an element is inefficient. Use a set for this, which will give O(log(n)) or O(1) time, instead of O(n). This job really calls for a database though.

Comment: If there are two (or more) users go through this "new account" logic, the code above would need some way to coordinate the total set of numbers ("nums"), and also guard against two of them both "finding" the same new number ("num") and proceeding ahead with that. There are real concurrency challenges awaiting you.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using databases to create a simple Bank Management system. I need
> to create user accounts with an account number with 9 digits, that
> does not start with 0. also, all the account numbers must be
> different. Every time I run the program, it should give me a 9-digit
> number that is not stored in the 'accounts' table under
> 'account_number' in the 'login_info' database.

This actually turns out to be an unexpectedly complicated question to answer.  The best answer depends upon other factors which you have not mentioned:

- Does the account number have to be unique "each time the program is run" or "each time an account number is requested during the same run (but not necessarily from run to run)"?
- Is this a single-threaded environment (i.e., how many simultaneously executing threads might be trying to create account numbers at the same time)?
- Does the account number have the sense of *identity*; does it need to be able to uniquely identify a specific account at all times (or are there times, perhaps when the account is being created from a form, when an account doesn't need to have identity?
- What manages the identity?  Your program system?  The database that you are using to store the information?

If the first bullet item answer is "each time the program is run", then you need to think about how the *account number seed* (the quantity or quantities that are used to generate your next available account number) is *persisted* from run to run (the seed otherwise is destroyed when the JVM exits).

If the second bullet item is "multiple threads", then you need to think about how to prevent the same account number from being inadvertently provided to threads requesting one at the same time.

The remaining bullet items deal with identity.  Account numbers are generally used to identify specific accounts to the system (but not necessarily).  So, you have to consider when the identity needs to become available to the system.  You also have to think about what system is responsible for managing the identity.  If the identity is needed as soon as an account entity is created, then it needs to be obtained during the instantiation of the account by Java.  If it is not needed until the account entity is persisted to the database, then it may be possible for the database system to create the identity.

A hybrid solution would be to persist the account as soon as it was instantiated, and then read it right back again to obtain the account number (at the cost of increasing database traffic).  Logic might be needed to delete the database record if the account did not need to be persisted after all (because, say, it had been canceled).

Depending on the answers to these questions, and upon other important factors such as availability, scalability, redundancy, security etc., the complete solution to the original problem could become arbitrarily complex.

But if we assume that account numbers need to be unique only during the same run of the Java system and that account accesses are only single threaded, then a solution could become very simple:

```
public static class AccountNumberManager {
    private static long accountNumberSeed = getStartupSeedValue();

    private AccountNumberManager() { }

    public long getNextAccountNumber() {
        return ++accountNumberSeed;
    }

    private static long getStartupSeedValue() {
        return 100000000L;
    }
}
```

Some brief notes:

- A `static` class for account number management makes the initialization of the account number seed value thread safe.  The initial value initialization occurs while the class is locked by the class loader during the loading process and is therefore thread safe (the class and its static fields can only be initialized once and once only).  This is the *static holder class initialization method*.  This would be handy if the system ever evolved into a concurrent environment.
- This solution, of course, assumes that the account number is needed when the account entity is initialized.  I think this is a good practice anyway.  My bias is that database systems should not be used to create system-wide identitifiers when possible (only to persist them).
- It is not a best practice to use account numbers as database primary keys.  This is an opinion that is fairly widely, not but universally, held.